# Unique Constraint doesn't appear to be constraining anything

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a Table called Models set up as follows:

1. ID - PK, Identity
2. Manufacturer FK - Int32
3. PriModel FK - Int32
4. SecModel FK - Int32
5. FormFactor FK - Int32
6. Active Char(1)

What I want is Columns 2,3,4,5 to only accept a unique set of values. I ran:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Models ADD CONSTRAINT uc_Models UNIQUE (Manufacturer, PriModel, SecModel, FormFactor)
```

The command reported completed successfully and I see an index was added, but not a constraint. I am also able to create a duplicate of cols 2-5 with Insert and Update commands. I'm not sure if the issue is the foreign keys or something else altogether.

```
USE [inventory_v2]
GO


    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Models]    Script Date: 4/8/2013 2:01:41 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Models](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Manufacturer] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PriModel] [int] NOT NULL,
        [SecModel] [int] NOT NULL,
        [FormFactor] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Active] [char](1) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Models] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
     CONSTRAINT [uc_Models] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [Manufacturer] ASC,
        [PriModel] ASC,
        [SecModel] ASC,
        [FormFactor] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_FormFactor] FOREIGN KEY([FormFactor])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Models_FormFactor] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_FormFactor]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_OEMs] FOREIGN KEY([Manufacturer])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Models_OEMs] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_OEMs]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_PriModels] FOREIGN KEY([PriModel])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Models_PriModels] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_PriModels]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_SecModels] FOREIGN KEY([SecModel])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Models_SecModels] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Models] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Models_Models_SecModels]
    GO
```

Comment: Are you sure the constraint was added correctly?  How did you verify?  Try `sp_help Models` and verify that the constraints section lists your new constraint, and that it is unique.

Comment: No. I looked in the SMS console. It is listed in that section as UNIQUE (non-clustered).

Comment: Are your duplicate values `null`?

Comment: No, they would be {2:2:3:1}. So Updating {2:2:4:1} to {2:2:3:1} is allowed to go through even though it already exists.

Comment: Weird (clearly why you're posting here!). Might help if you post the table definition obtained via 'Script Table As...'

Comment: Added to the main post.

Comment: Well, when I copy and paste that, and replace your `[dbo].[Models]` with `#tbl`, and execute it up to `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF`, it works as expected; I get an error message when I try to insert twice.  Note that `alter index uc_Models on [dbo].[Models] disable` would show the behaviour you describe, and doesn't appear to alter the table create script. Try `alter index uc_Models on [dbo].[Models] rebuild`

Comment: I realized I needed to set some of the columns to unique on the Tables where the FKs were stored. After I did that it started working. I think something must have been off server side. Lag, Latency, or the price of iPhones for Aboriginies must have kicked the server in the pants.